# How to divide numbers more accurately in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, precision

I'm trying to make a calculation which takes in the number `1034.55` and divide it by 0.05 and then truncate off all the numbers.

If I do 1034.55/0.05 on the Windows and Android calculator, it gives 20691. Within python however, it gives:

```
>>> 1034.55/0.05
20690.999999999996
```

Obiously when I truncate the decimal places, this is now one lower number than expected. When working with floats, There must be up to 5 digits accuracy.

How am I able to solve this rounding issue due to floating point accuracy(?) while keeping the performance? I am currently doing `chunk["index"] = np.trunc(chunk["num"] / 0.05)`

I have tried to multiply the number by 100000 first to try and do maths on an integer but this added too much delay in the performance. I've also seen there is an `import doubles` module but this won't be as fast as numpy?

Comment: Why not multiply by `20` rather than divide by `0.05`?

Comment: For the same reason, in accounting (finance, banks, etc.) they use integers (e.g. number of cents, or "milli-dollars" or something like that (so "fix decimal point"). If you know that 0.05 is the minimal unit: just use factor of it (and you convert to float only for displaying and figures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To round it to the nearest integer use `round()`:

```
int(round(num/0.05),5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just round it to the nearest integer using the built in `round()` function.

Alternativly you can specify if it rounds to the bigger or smaller number using the functions `ceil()` (always to bigger number) and `floor()` (alway to smaller number) from the math library:

```
from math import floor, ceil

mynumber = floor(mynumber)
mynum = ceil(mynum)
```

or

```
import math

mynumber = math.floor(mynumber)
mynum = math.ceil(mynum)
```